# Issues changing border color in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, dom-manipulation

I am submitting a form, and it has validation to make sure my text box has a value. If `false`, the alert displays fine, however I can't get the border to change color. I can't seem to find out what I am doing wrong.

```
<script>
    function validate(){
        var dob = document.forms["ppm"]["dob"].value;
        if(dob == ""){
            document.getElementById("dob").style.border="red";
            alert("Error");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>

<form onsubmit="return validate()" name="ppm" id="ppm" action="index.php" method="post">

<p>What is your DOB<br />
<input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" value="" />

<input type="submit" name="Continue" value="Continue"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to give the border the some width before it will be visible. You can use the individual `border*` properties for that:

```
document.getElementById("dob").style.borderColor ="red";
document.getElementById("dob").style.borderWidth ="2px";
```

Or, stick with `border` but supply a full border value (width, style, and color):

```
document.getElementById("dob").style.border = "2px solid red";
```

Here's a working example slightly modified from your original:

```js
function validate() {
  var dob = document.getElementById('dob').value;
  if (dob == null || dob == '') {
    document.getElementById("dob").style.border = "2px solid red";
    alert("Error");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>What is your DOB
  <br />
  <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" value="" />

  <input type="button" onclick="validate()" name="Continue" value="Continue" />
```

I'm tempted to rewrite your `validate` function into something like this:

```
function validate() {
  var dobEl = document.getElementById('dob'); // only get it once
  if (!(dobEl.value || '').length)) { // if null or empty
    dobEl.style.border = "2px solid red"; // set the style
    alert("Error");
    return false; // don't submit the form
  } else {
    // set the border back to normal
  }
  return true; // do submit the form
}
```

Comment: I have actually tried both of these, still nothing.

Comment: Check your logic -- what you have in your post would produce errors on it's own (e.g. `signer` would cause an issue because it doesn't exist). Run my example to see that it should indeed work if incorporated correctly. I changed how it retrieves and checks the `dob` value, and removed the `signer` part to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks, this was only a snip of the other 60 fields i am validating. Could the issue be the way I am defining the inputs using 'document.forms'? or same with the <form onsubmit="return validate()"> at the start of the form

Comment: I guess I am just going to have to go back and change everything to a more simple format or jQuery

Comment: I would suggest `document.getElementById()` to find your form and its controls, since they all do seem to have unique IDs. The array notation is ancient and is probably not as fast as what I just described.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an end tag on your paragraph (`</p>`).  You also need to set all parts of the border property when using `style.border`.  Below is a working example.

```js
    var isValid = function () {
        var dob = document.forms["ppm"]["dob"].value;
    
        if (dob === "") {
            document.getElementById("dob").style.border = "solid 1px red";
            
            alert("Error");
            
            return false;
        }
        
        return true;
    };
```

```html
    <form onsubmit="return isValid();" name="ppm" id="ppm" action="index.php" method="post">
        <p>What is your DOB</p>
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" value="" />
        <input type="submit" name="Continue" value="Continue" />
    </form>
```